# How to detect a wxFrame is focued or not in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I want to detect when my frame got focused. The events that I handled are `EVT_SET_FOCUS` and `EVT_KILL_FOCUS` [Ref](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.0/classwx_focus_event.html). They work but not always! and I don't know why in some cases the focus or blur event does not get triggered. Should I also handle `EVT_ACTIVATE`? In what cases, focus event does not get triggered (focusing happens but no events get published)?

My OS is Win 10 and I am using the 3.1.5 version of WxWidgets.

Comment: I think you already know when the EVT_SET_FOCUS is not triggered. Now are trying to catch it in the TLW or some child? Also - what is `blur event`?

Comment: @Igor what I mean by 'blur' event is when a widget lose focus (in wxwidgets is equal to 'kill_focus' )I don't know why focus event is not triggered sometimes. I don't have a complex setting. A simple frame with no child. What I do is that I change the focus to another application and then click again on the frame. So normally the focus event should happen. But it is not and I am looking for the reason.

Comment: so you are working with the TLW. In this case you probably need EVT_ACTIVATE. Especially, since there is no child controls on the frame...

Comment: Are you calling `event.Skip()`. It is easier if you share your code.